# Ajax call to populate form fields from php returned object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Firstly I use the `$.getJSON()` sending the user ID using GET request.

Javascrit part:

```
        $.getJSON("this_file.php?id=1", null, function(data){
            $('input#id').val(data.id);
            $('input#username').val(data.username);
            $('input#first_name').val(data.first_name);
        });
```

When reveicing the user ID via GET request, I run a function to return to me an OBJECT with user details.

PHP part (this_file.php):

```
    <?php
        $id =  $_GET['id'];
        $user = $db->find_by_id($id); //This function will return a single user details.
        echo json_encode($user);
     ,  //echo $user output is: {"id" : "1", "username" : "bobu", "first_name" : "bob"} 
     ?>
```

Here are the form fields to be populated.

HTML Form:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="id" id="id">
<input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username">
<input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="first_name">
```

In the browser console, the response from the GET request is returned as expected:

`{"id" : "1", "username" : "bobu", "first_name" : "bob"}`

However, the values are not being displayed on the form, how do I make this approach?

Comment: Are you getting any error message in the javascript console?

Comment: Not at all, it successfully returns the expected data, it just doesn't update the form fields

Comment: you dont need to use input#id, just use `$('#id').val(data.id);`

Comment: I have followed your advice but I believe that wouldn't be what is causing the issue.

Comment: Is content-type: application/json returned in response headers? If not I'd try to set it explicitly on PHP side.

Comment: console.dir(data) and explicitly take a look whats inside !

Comment: There's an object inside - Object: {readyState : 4, responseText : {"id" : "1", "username" : "bobu", "first_name" : "bob"}, status : 200, statusText : "OK"}

Comment: Something isn't adding up. `data` in callback should only be `{"id" : "1", "username" : "bobu", "first_name" : "bob"}` Somehow you are accessing the xhr object

Answer (score 0):

I'd use javascript but if your not going to:

**Change**

```
<input type="text" value="" name="id" id="id">
<input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username">
<input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="first_name">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if($sentVar==1){echo $id;} ?>" name="id" id="id">
<input type="text" value="<?php if($sentVar==1){echo $username;} ?>" name="username" id="username">
<input type="text" value="<?php if($sentVar==1){echo $first_name;} ?>" name="first_name" id="first_name">
```

then add a condition in the PHP when it triggers:

```
$sentVar=1;
```

or just try:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id" id="id">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name="username" id="username">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" name="first_name" id="first_name">
```